# Vscode java inlay hints not showing for preferenced libraries

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I enabled inlay hints for java, and it's working but only for the local classes and methods. When i imported a preferenced library, it doesn't showed the parameter name. Is it possible to enable something or download an extension to show the hints?

And that library is mine, so i can do anything with it to make it work.

This is a local class:
[image]

And this is the main class:
[image]

Comment: I am sorry, but could you provide a screenshot or an example of it? I am afraid misunderstand your problem thanks.

Comment: @Steven-MSFT I did, hopefully you can help me with the screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the source jars are needed to display the inlay hint. (The parameter names could not be resolved without sources)

The first thing you can do is try to go to the definition of a class from your referenced libraries, to check if you can see the source code or just some decompiled signatures. If you can see the source but the inlay hint is not showing, please file an issue in the GitHub repo.

Comment: My reference libraries are loaded the code, so can you please give me a link, where should i file my issue in GitHub?

Comment: Maybe you can checkout this. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_manage-dependencies-for-unmanaged-folder

Comment: I couldn't find any information from it.

Comment: Check if using the `sources` field in the setting `java.project.referencedLibraries` could help. If not, you can file issue at: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-pack/issues/new/choose